# Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `active` with styled-components and react.js

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm getting an error message saying

```
Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `active`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: active="false" or active={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with active={condition && value}, pass active={condition ? value : undefined} instead.
```

and my code looks like this

index.jsx

```
import { Container, CalendarIcon } from "./styles";

export default function App() {

  const isActive = context => context === activePopover;

  return (
    <Container>
       ...
      <CalendarIcon active={isActive(POPOVERS.Date)} />
       ...    
    </Container>
  );
}
```

styles.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {default as CalendarRoundIconSvg} from './CalendarRoundIcon.tsx';

export const isActive = active => (active ? `#04435e` : `#9b9fa3`);

export const CalendarIcon = styled(CalendarRoundIconSvg).attrs(({active}) => ({
  color: isActive(active),
}))`
`;
```

CalendarRoundIcon.tsx

```
const CalendarRoundIcon: React.FC<SvgIconProps> = props => {
  const {color = 'currentColor'} = props;
  return (
    <SvgIcon
      width="14"
      height="14"
      viewBox="0 0 14 14"
      fill={color}
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      {...props}
    >
      <path
        d="M4.47109 8.49349H3.51286C3.40199 8.49313 3.29577 8.45107 3.21737 8.37648C3.13897 8.30189 3.09476 8.20082 3.09439 8.09534V7.18363C3.09476 7.07808 3.13895 6.97695 3.21733 6.90225C3.2957 6.82755 3.40192 6.78534 3.51286 6.7848H4.47109C4.58209 6.78534 4.68839 6.82753 4.76688 6.90221C4.84537 6.97689 4.88971 7.07802 4.89027 7.18363V8.09534C4.88971 8.20089 4.84534 8.30195 4.76683 8.37652C4.68832 8.45109 4.58202 8.49314 4.47109 8.49349Z"
        fill={color}
      />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
};

export default memo(CalendarRoundIcon);
```

`index.jsx` there is a `isActive` function return boolean and I pass this function as a `active props` to the styled component.

in styled component(`styles.js`), there is also a function that returns color hex based on the `active props` that passed from the `index.jsx`

and lastly passing color to the icon file.

How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: Try `$active` on `CalendarIcon`

Answer (score 2):

Added `$active` on CalendarIcon solved this problem!

```
import { Container, CalendarIcon } from "./styles";

export default function App() {

  const isActive = context => context === activePopover;

  return (
    <Container>
       ...
      <CalendarIcon $active={isActive(POPOVERS.Date)} />
       ...    
    </Container>
  );
}
```

also styled.jsx you need to change the word `active` to `$active`

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {default as CalendarRoundIconSvg} from './CalendarRoundIcon.tsx';

export const isActive = active => (active ? `#04435e` : `#9b9fa3`);

export const CalendarIcon = styled(CalendarRoundIconSvg).attrs(({$active}) => ({
  color: isActive($active),
}))`
`;
```

Comment: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props it's called `transient props` btw